# Can't figure out why my mouse picking code doesn't work

Tags: c++, directx, directx11, raycasting, picking

I am trying to create code to check for intersections between bounding spheres and the mouse. I get a mouse ray but it doesnt seem to point in the direction you think it should Attached is a screenshot and code. If anyone can help I would appreciate it as this is driving me crazy.

[image: Ray Error]

```
    auto state = m_mouse->GetState();

    float mouseX = state.x;
    float mouseY = state.y;
    float m_screenWidth = m_deviceResources->GetScreenViewport().Width;
    float m_screenHeight = m_deviceResources->GetScreenViewport().Height;

    // Normalized device coordinates
    float x = (2.0f * mouseX) / m_screenWidth - 1.0f;
    float y = 1.0f - (2.0f * mouseY) / m_screenHeight;

    DirectX::XMMATRIX viewMatrix = DirectX::XMMatrixTranspose(DirectX::XMLoadFloat4x4(&cameraComponentHandle->view));
    DirectX::XMMATRIX projectionMatrix = DirectX::XMMatrixTranspose(DirectX::XMLoadFloat4x4(&cameraComponentHandle->projection));
    DirectX::XMMATRIX inverseviewproj = DirectX::XMMatrixInverse(nullptr, viewMatrix * projectionMatrix);

    DirectX::SimpleMath::Vector3 origin = DirectX::SimpleMath::Vector3(x, y, 0);
    DirectX::SimpleMath::Vector3 farPoint = DirectX::SimpleMath::Vector3(x, y, 1);

    DirectX::SimpleMath::Vector3 rayorigin = DirectX::XMVector3TransformCoord(origin, inverseviewproj);
    DirectX::SimpleMath::Vector3 rayend = DirectX::XMVector3TransformCoord(farPoint, inverseviewproj);
    DirectX::SimpleMath::Vector3 raydirection = (rayend - rayorigin);
    raydirection.Normalize();

    rayComponentHandle->position = rayorigin;
    rayComponentHandle->direction = raydirection;
```

Comment: Can you attach a mesh to your ray so you can see how it's moving around?

Comment: Yeah there is a cube attached to the origin which follows the mouse its just the direction that seems off.

Comment: I would use that to do a bit of troubleshooting. Eg, put the mouse at (0,0) and see where is the ray? Try at centre screen. Try moving on the y-axis and the x-axis. See how your cube responds

Comment: A tip: (I don't know if this will work) In your origin/farpoint, use the near-plane and far-plane instead of 0 and 1

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out the code is correct and my problem was with the rendering of the ray itself. I was calculating a world matrix when the coordinates were already in worldspace.